# ExoPlayer starts video with a black screen for 0.3 sec in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer

I have `ExoPlayer` with Compose and it works:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            val defaultDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
            val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(
                context,
                defaultDataSourceFactory
            )

            val packageName = context.applicationContext.packageName
            val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://${packageName}/${R.raw.xeal_tutorial_compressed}")
            val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))

            setMediaSource(source)
            prepare()
            playWhenReady = true
            repeatMode = REPEAT_MODE_ONE
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            PlayerView(context).apply {
                player = exoPlayer
            }
        }
    )
```

The problem is that first 0.3 sec I see black screen when it starts first time. I think it's rendering problems.
If I would use `XML` file with `VideoView` I would set

```
videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true)
```

which I used before compose era.
How to solve this problem in Compose ExoPlayer?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/ui/PlayerView#getVideoSurfaceView()
If you want to achieve the SurfaceView (VideoView), i think this will help

Comment: @VanSuTuyDuyen I don't understand how it is related to my problem. Do I have to use PlayerView somehow?

Comment: your code is used PlayerView inside AndroidView, right. And with the function i described you can 1) get the surfaceview by call `getVideoSurfaceView()` 2) call `setZOrderOnTop(true)` on that surfaceview, because videoView extends SurfaceView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could avoid initial 0.3 sec black screen only when I separated an initialization of `ExoPlayer` and its usage in `PlayerView` by time.
The main point is to give some time for new created `ExoPlayer` to prepare for work.
In my case I created `ExoPlayer` in `viewModel` and then pass it to `Composable` function where `PlayerView` uses it. After usage a dismiss function in `viewModel` is activated to clear `ExoPlayer`

Comment: can you provide code snippet, how did you handle it?

Answer (score 0):

By adjusting the zIndex values, you can control the order in which Composables are drawn and achieve the overlay effect similar to setZOrderOnTop(true).

> ```
> import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
> import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
> import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
> import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
> import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
> import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
> import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
> import androidx.compose.ui.zIndex
> import androidx.navigation.NavController
> import com.google.accompanist.exoplayer.ExoPlayer
> import com.google.accompanist.exoplayer.rememberVideoPlayerController
>
> @Composable
> fun VideoPlayerOverlay() {
>     val videoPlayerController = rememberVideoPlayerController()
>     videoPlayerController.setSource("your_video_url_here")
>
>     Box(
>         modifier = Modifier
>             .fillMaxSize()
>     ) {
>         // Content underneath the video
>         Text(
>             text = "This is some content",
>             fontSize = 24.sp,
>             modifier = Modifier
>                 .fillMaxSize()
>                 .background(Color.White)
>                 .zIndex(1f) // Place this content on a higher layer
>         )
>
>         // Video player overlay
>         ExoPlayer(
>             exoPlayer = videoPlayerController,
>             modifier = Modifier
>                 .fillMaxSize()
>                 .zIndex(2f) // Place the video player on top
>         )
>     }
> }
>
> @Preview
> @Composable
> fun VideoPlayerOverlayPreview() {
>     VideoPlayerOverlay()
> }
> ```

Comment: no, it doesn't help. I tried it and other way to fix it and me helped only separation of creation and usage of an exoPlayer. And a main idea is to give some time for a player to prepare playing

Answer (score 0):

In Jetpack Compose, you can control the rendering order of composables using the Modifier.zIndex modifier. To address the issue of a black screen appearing for the first 0.3 seconds when your ExoPlayer starts for the first time, you can adjust the rendering order to ensure that the ExoPlayer's PlayerView is rendered on top of other elements. Here's how you can do it:

```
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultDataSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoSize
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoSurfaceView
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoView

@Composable
fun VideoPlayer() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val exoPlayer = remember {
        SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            val defaultDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
            val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(
                context,
                defaultDataSourceFactory
            )

            val packageName = context.applicationContext.packageName
            val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://${packageName}/${R.raw.xeal_tutorial_compressed}")
            val source = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)

            setMediaItem(source)
            prepare()
            playWhenReady = true
            repeatMode = ExoPlayer.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
        }
    }

    // Use the AndroidView composable with Modifier.zIndex to control the rendering order
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            VideoView(context).apply {
                player = exoPlayer
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize() // You can adjust this modifier as needed
            .zIndex(1f) // Set the zIndex to ensure it's rendered on top
    )
}
```

In the code above, we use the Modifier.zIndex(1f) modifier to set the rendering order of the VideoView with ExoPlayer to be on top of other elements. This should help eliminate the black screen issue during the initial playback. Adjust the Modifier as needed to fit your layout.

Make sure you have the necessary ExoPlayer dependencies included in your project for this code to work.